# Command to "format" txt Files

Tags: command

I have several TXT files like the example bellow in a certain solder:

```
5600001254545 - Bar code
12 - Quantity
5600000785487 - Bar code
250 - Quantity
```

I need to writte a code to place the line of the quantity in front of the code bar, separated by; in all the files without opening them one by one or doing it on Excel.

Can you please help me?

Regards,

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Given that the question contains "or doing it on Excel", probably Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with a text editor supporting regular expressions (Maybe Editplus, Textpad++, ...).

Open your text files with such editor and replace "Bar code\n" by "Bar code;". This way you will have just one line with both the barcode and the quantity data.

Comment: He would still have to open all the files one by one that way. He needs an editor that supports regex "from the outside"...